# What is the ram-facing side of spacecraft?

Tags: astrophysics

what is the ram-facing side of  a satellite? What does it mean and why is it called "ram"-facing? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following picture is from a simulation for a satellite moving through the ionospheric plasma.

[image: ionospheric plasma]

The **Ram** side is the side that points in the direction of the satellite's motion. It is called the ram side because it is the side impacting/ramming into the fluid that the satellite moves through. In this case it is the ionosphere. If the fluid's velocity is comparable to the satellite then it is a little more complicated.

The **Wake** side is exactly the opposite. It faces away from the the satellite's motion and thus does not impact the fluid as much. The satellite's motion creates a wake behind it like a boat through the water.